# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable even after updates

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

So I was trying to create a whatsapp automation bot using sublime text.
The Code goes like this :

```
    from selenium import webdriver


    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')


    name = raw_input('Enter Name Of Group/User :')

    msg = raw_input('Enter Message :')

    count = int(input('Enter Count :'))


    raw_input("Press Enter After Scanning")


    user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title = "{}"]'.format(name))

    user.click()


    msg_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('X7YrQ')


    for i in range(count):

    msg_box.send_keys(msg)

    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3M-N-')

    driver.implicitly_wait(10)


    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
```

When I run it , its just opening the chat box and stays there.
The error shown :

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
```

Things I tried :
Updating my drivers

Updating selenium libraries 
Checking for updates
Adding a timer

I write a simple code to check selenium:

```
enter browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Error shown :

```
    NameError: name 'webdriver' is not defined
```

Please help me sort this out.

PS : Am a partial script kiddie so some lines of code would be helpful

PPS : All the above files plus the installation commands are provided in the link 
[Installation Codes](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X9_MzRUWLFVgAIClRePRuE0seouEOG6i) [Main Code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IUwn0UdMFQDjzE3Ah4gXJI5eSboxpyEr) [Second Test Program](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZcIxCBesLOFkqnFwWEbGKqvDvtsYq2TI)

Answer (score 0):

If the driver is not in the same folder you should specify the location in

`browser = webdriver.Chrome('<driver location>')`

also here :

```
enter browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

I think the problem was that you didn't import the webdriver

Answer (score 0):

First error:
You must add path to chromedriver, as first argument like this

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver')
```

Second error: you need to install selenium library from [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html)